# How to add a Fancybox inside a modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, fancybox

I am trying to use fancybox and put the images inside of a modal and, when i click on the image, another modal shows over the first one. The problem is that the big picture stays behind the main modal and it is bigger than the screen. How can i fix this? Is it possible or i have to create another page for using fancybox? Thanks in advance.

**PartialView inside of modal content:**

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + x.FileName)" title="@x.FileTitle"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + x.FileName)" alt="" /></a>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'over'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**AJAX call:**

```
$Modal.on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $Modal.find(".modal-content .modal-body").html(htmlSpinner);
    $.get('@Url.Action("ModalDetails")', { id: $(".mybutton").val() }, function (data) {
        $Modal.find(".modal-content .modal-body").html(data);
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public PartialViewResult ModalDetails(Guid id)
    {
        var temp = db.Ticket_Message_Files.Where(o => o.IdTicketMessage == id && o.FileType == 0).ToList();
        var model = new List<DAL.Ticket_Message_Files>();

        foreach (var x in temp)
        {
            DAL.Ticket_Message_Files file = new DAL.Ticket_Message_Files
            {
                FileOriginalName = x.FileOriginalName,
                FileName = x.FileName,
                FileTitle = x.FileTitle,
                FileType = x.FileType,
                IdTicketMessage = x.IdTicketMessage
            };
            model.Add(file);
        }
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Here are the results:

[image: Main modal]

[image: Fancybox view]

Comment: You could upgrade to fancyBox v3 and use it for displaying modal while image is opened, because it supports multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `fancybox({` after appending data to the modal-body as fancy box is not bind to the element which is not in DOM yet so after appending data to modal body you have to call  `fancybox({` function please find below for more information

```
$Modal.on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $Modal.find(".modal-content .modal-body").html(htmlSpinner);
    $.get('@Url.Action("ModalDetails")', { id: $(".mybutton").val() }, function (data) {
        $Modal.find(".modal-content .modal-body").html(data);

//after appending data to modal body
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'over'
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still not working as it should.

Comment: look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/83/) as well i have created example here may be this'll help

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot. Your code is right but the problem is that i linked the css as a script, so the style didn't work as he should. Thanks for the help, appreciate that.

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia Ohh no worries happens sometimes you are always welcome glad it helps you cheers :)